# How to find which admin delete posts in Telegram supergroup?

Tags: telegram

Is there any way to find which one of supergroup admins (in Telegram) delete a special post?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way** to find out who deleted message at this time.

I think you can suggest this feature to official Twitter, or support account.